# PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant X, assumed Y

Tags: php

**Error in logs:**

> Use of undefined constant img - assumed 'img' in
>   /home/indiay4s/public_html/101hot.com/xxx/view.php on line 6
>
> Use of undefined constant time - assumed 'time' in
>   /home/indiay4s/public_html/101hot.com/xxx/view.php on line 8
>
> Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in
>   /home/indiay4s/public_html/101hot.com/xxx/view.php on line 10
>
> Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in
>   /home/indiay4s/public_html/101hot.com/xxx/view.php on line 12

**Relevant lines of code:**

```
<?
include 'header.php';
?>

<div class="fl odd">
<img src="<?=$_GET[img]?>">
</br></br>
<div class="M2 c18"><strong>Duration:&nbsp;<span class="bld"><?=$_GET[time]?> Min</strong></div>

<div class="M2 c18"><strong><a href="index.php?id=<?=$_GET[id]?>" class="dwn">Download MP4 HQ </a></strong></div>

<div class="M2 c18"><strong><a href="index.php?id=<?=$_GET[id]?>" class="dwn">Download MP4 </a></strong></div>

</div>


<?
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: You probably want to use `img` as string and not as constant for the index.

Comment: `<img src="<?=$_GET["img"]?>">`, same applies to $_GET[time] and to $_GET[id]